# Phonegap/Cordova facebook plugin not working on version 3.0

Tags: facebook, cordova

Tried to install [facebook plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) with Cordova 3.0 but it's not working. I tried using various branches which seem updated but none found is working. At least with the automated installer.

Is there a version of this plugin ported to Cordova 3.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a branch of the plugin that is working(almost) with the new plugin architecture in 3.0. The branch is located [here](https://github.com/Raffaello/phonegap-facebook-plugin). 
Plugman does not work so you have to manually install it. After installation you need to remove the .api in ConnectPlugin.java package names:

```
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
```